# How to remove the info message "Not storing invalid cookie" from Jmeter log

Tags: jmeter

While running my Jmeter test I am observing too many following info logs,
Using Jmeter 5.2, any clue how to exclude them from the log?

```
2020-08-04 06:35:10,791 INFO o.a.j.p.h.c.HC4CookieHandler: Not storing invalid cookie: <ARRAffinity=a1f37308d413bb137a826fb2decbf7470273035f292c1941d98553b758805914;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=<domain_url>> for URL https://application_url.com/apicountries/(Illegal 'domain' attribute "<domain_url>". Domain of origin: "application_url.com")
2020-08-04 06:35:13,469 INFO o.a.j.p.h.c.HC4CookieHandler: Not storing invalid cookie: <ARRAffinity=a1f37308d413bb137a826fb2decbf7470273035f292c1941d98553b758805914;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=<domain_url>> for URL https://application_url.com/apicountries/(Illegal 'domain' attribute "<domain_url>". Domain of origin: "application_url.com")
2020-08-04 06:35:19,925 INFO o.a.j.p.h.c.HC4CookieHandler: Not storing invalid cookie: <ARRAffinity=a1f37308d413bb137a826fb2decbf7470273035f292c1941d98553b758805914;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=<domain_url>> for URL https://application_url.com/api/countries/89 (Illegal 'domain' attribute "<domain_url>". Domain of origin: "application_url.com")
2020-08-04 06:35:27,813 INFO o.a.j.p.h.c.HC4CookieHandler: Not storing invalid cookie: <ARRAffinity=a1f37308d413bb137a826fb2decbf7470273035f292c1941d98553b758805914;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=<domain_url>> for URL https://application_url.com/apicountries/(Illegal 'domain' attribute "<domain_url>". Domain of origin: "application_url.com")
2020-08-04 06:35:45,154 INFO o.a.j.p.h.c.HC4CookieHandler: Not storing invalid cookie: <ARRAffinity=a1f37308d413bb137a826fb2decbf7470273035f292c1941d98553b758805914;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=<domain_url>> for URL https://application_url.com/apicountries/(Illegal 'domain' attribute "<domain_url>". Domain of origin: "application_url.com")
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57144204/10858089

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the next line to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation):

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC4CookieHandler" level="off" />
```

JMeter restart will be required in order to apply the change.

More information:

- [Log4j - Custom Log Levels](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html)
- [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging)
- [Logging and error messages](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)